# How to create a mask/filter for vue signature?

Tags: css, vue.js

Currently, this is the e-signature pad which I am using and it is working. https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-signature/-/vue-signature-2.5.1

[image]

The problem is if the user sign the signature too near to the border, the signature will not be captured.

Below is the failed e-signature.

[image]

How do I add a mask/filter to add some spacing between the borders?

[image]

so that even if the user sign near the border, the output will still have the spacing around the borders.

[image]

This is the current code in pug:

```
.esign--pad-control: .esign--pad-container
  .esign--pad
    vuesignature(
      id="signaturePad",
      ref='eSign', 
      :sigOption='{ penColor:"rgb(0, 0, 0)", backgroundColor:"rgb(255,255,255)" }'
    )
```

and the styles:

```
.esign--pad-control {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.esign--pad-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.esign--pad {
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px dashed #d5d5d5;

  @include MQ(XSM) {
    border: 4px dashed #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }    
}
```

This is the generated html from the package. I got it from inspect.

```
<div id="signaturePad" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas id="canvas894" data-uid="canvas894" class="canvas" width="442" style="touch-action: none;" height="192"></canvas></div>
<canvas id="canvas894" data-uid="canvas894" class="canvas" width="442" style="touch-action: none;" height="192"></canvas>
</div>
```

Can I use `before` or `after` pseudo-element to do this?

I tried to add image before the canvas with this code.

```
.esign--pad-control: .esign--pad-container
  .esign--pad
    .esign--pad--inner            
      img(src="../../../assets/images/signature.png",class="sign-bg")        
      vuesignature(
        id="signaturePad",
        ref='eSign', 
        :sigOption='{ penColor:"rgb(0, 0, 0)", backgroundColor:"rgb(255,255,255)"}'
      )
```

and the styles:

```
.esign--pad--inner { 
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.sign-bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Now, it looks good on the user interface, but it is not signable because the image is on 'top' of the signature pad. Any solution?

[image]